# Unable to finish entering input in Intellij for BufferedReader

Tags: java

So I've been trying to create a program that reads lines from standard input and produces a count on lines, words and alphanumeric characters. The problem is that I can't test it because the console doesn't know when my input is finished. Below are some pictures to illustrate my problem:

[Input I need to enter for testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35ZnZ.png)

[The problem...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQZVd.png)

Note the second picture is in continuation after the first one, I am unable to end the input process. Now I have a condition in my while loop:

while (br.readLine != null)

Does this condition create an infinite loop or is there some IntelliJ feature I should know about to end my input?

Comment: "I am unable to end the input process"... actually intellij console does support ctrl-d: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/debug-tool-window-console.html

Comment: Thank you scrappedcola, this fixed my problem!